# Auth0 Authentication Flow (Mismatching State)

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, auth0

I hope whoever's reading this is having a good day!

My question is as follows, I'am getting a Mismatching state error when following this flow.

Given FrontEnd is hosted on domain FE (React Client), backEnd on domain BE (DJango Server) and Auth0 on A0.

**Flow's picture**
[Flow details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4rJX.jpg)

```
def callback(request):
    '''
        Extracts state and auth code from url, authenticates with auth0,
        extracts token and saves it within the request session for future
        calls.
    '''
    token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token(request)
    request.session["user"] = token
    return {"Authenticated":True}


def login(request):
    '''
        Redirect to auth0 login screen with a callback url to frontend
        that extracts the given state and auth code sent by both BE and Auth0
    '''
    return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(
        request, "http://FrontEnd.com/authenticate")
```

What happens when doing so is that the backend receives the state and raises a Mismatching state error request and response states do not match (state is null)

If my callback url is directly the backend then things tend to work with no problems, but having the frontend domain initiate this request causes the above error.

Why do I want to do that? is because I have multiple microservices and I dont want each to have its own API that redirects to it after authenticating.

A theory to why this might be happening is because I receive a cookie (sessionId) from BE in the first step and when FE tries to create a request from its domain with the auth code and state, the cookie isn't transferred as its not a cross origin cookie.